# Problem with display after suspending

Tags: 16.04, display

I faced strange issue, as usual after wake up (during work),
every popup window  (menu, list and etc) appeared with with a border
like on the picture. Ubuntu 16.04. Only relogin or restarting helps. It never happened before this week.

[image]

Comment: Yes, look at  Kaz Wolfe answer it contains link to this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we go [again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-from-suspend/897641#897641)...

This is currently a bug with [NVIDIA's drivers](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1667158), and is pending a fix on their end. In the meantime, a [bug against Compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830/) was opened to solve the same issue. While we wait for *someone* to fix this, there are still workarounds:

- **Downgrade Drivers**
  This bug was introduced after driver 367.57. Therefore, just downgrading to that version (or lower) will resolve this issue. Some users have reported success downgrading to 370.28 as well.
- **Switch to Intel graphics**
  If you're running NVIDIA Prime/Optimus, switching your system to use the integrated Intel card will resolve this issue. Note, however, that this will result in a pretty sharp performance loss.
- **Use An Experimental Patch**
  [Kai-Heng Feng](https://launchpad.net/~kaihengfeng) from the aforementioned Compiz bug report has released a modified version of `unity` on [his PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kaihengfeng/+archive/ubuntu/lp1292830) which resolves this problem pending a more formal fix from either Unity/Compiz or NVIDIA. To install this patch, run the below commands, and then reboot:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kaihengfeng/lp1292830 
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```

In the meantime, a temporary workaround to this same problem would be to run the `unity` command from a terminal or the Alt-F2 menu every time this issue is encountered.

Comment: Nice set of workarounds.

Comment: Note that running `unity` will close any open applications.

Answer (score 3):

I made some steps which solve my problem, but don't know what exactly helps
1. I change driver to X.org open source from NVIDIA
[image]

2. Install all system updates
3. Restarted OS, issue didn't occurred after it...

I hope it helps me... After it I tried to returned NVIDIA drivers... and it works well.. may be video drivers was corrupted.

Comment: I have the same problem  with the same drivers. I wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: I didn't face issue anymore.... these steps helps me

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak see Kaz answer [here.](http://askubuntu.com/a/897871/225694) for more options.

Comment: This worked for me. Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 1):

Kaz Wolfe said to downgrade to at least 367.57 or lower, but I downgraded my nvidia driver version to 370.28 and the problem is gone.

Also, I downgraded to an open source version and not proprietary.