# Window Rendering Problem

Tags: window-manager

I am having an issue in Ubuntu 16.04 . When I open a window such as a terminal window or the attached file properties window, the window border including the close , minimize etc icons are obscured by colored noise. What could be causing this?  I have lived with this for a while but it's becoming very frustrating. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: And also this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-from-suspend