# Problem with window drop shadow on Unity after system wakeup

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz

I had this problem once before in a previous version (don't remember which) and it is back again.

To create this, all I have to do is suspend my laptop and bring it back up again. At this point once I login back, the drop shadow on all the windows become messed up (see image). The corners (of the drop shadow) have some pink static noise and the borders form random lines.

[image: Messed up drop shadow]

This happens on all the application windows. If I reboot the laptop the problem goes away and promptly appears the next time I suspend/resume. This is same fate for newly opened windows.

- Ubuntu 16.04, Unity, Ambiance theme, GeForce GT 630M using Nvidia driver v375.39

Looking around for anyone having a similar problem I saw suggestions for dealing with problems with the drop shadow using CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager). The suggestion to 'override Theme Settings' in 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin' has not helped. However, there seems to be a temporary fix if I enable the setting and disable it. i.e. the messy drop shadow disappears (for newer windows too) but the 'close/minimize/restore' buttons become pink noise.

Any suggestion on what I could do next to solve this would be helpful. I renamed the `~/.cache/conpizconfig-1` folder hoping some texture cache that might have messed up would clear up, but with no success.

Comment: This is apparently a bug in nvidia driver, only happens when waking from suspend. Check this answer - http://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-from-suspend