# Nvidia drivers: Second screen not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a very annoying problem with my Asus laptop. I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M graphics card with an HDMI port and I want to connect a second monitor to it. If I use the Intel graphics card, everything works perfectly fine. Instead, if I use the performance mode, the second monitor is completely unusable: it shows artifacts and remains frozen. Here are some details on my system:

```
~ > inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
       X.Org: 1.15.1 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
       GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 378.13 Direct Rendering: Yes

~ > dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                                            3.2.1-9~gpu14.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-378                                                  378.13-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.3                             amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 378.13
ii  nvidia-378-dev                                              378.13-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.3                             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-prime                                                0.6.2.1linuxmint1                                      amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-prime-applet                                         1.0.3                                                  all          An applet for NVIDIA Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                             346.72-0ubuntu1                                        amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
~ >                      
~ > 
~ > dpkg -l | grep bumblebee
ii  bumblebee                                                   3.2.1-9~gpu14.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                                            3.2.1-9~gpu14.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
```

I also post a screenshot that shows that the two monitors are not detected correctly.
[image]

I saw some threads about similar problems but none of the solutions seemed to apply. Can someone help me?

Comment: *"it shows artifacts and remains frozen"* - It is possible that you are experiencing another manifestation of this bug: http://askubuntu.com/q/896221/518562