# How to remove these border artifacts?

Tags: 16.04, graphics, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts

Note: this is not a dupe of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode), as my computer has an AMD graphics chip, and *not* an Nvidia graphics chip

[image]
[image]

This appeared after I have turned off my laptop by pressing and holding a power button. Before that, I have done a few system updates, that there waiting for reboot (I keep laptop ON or on stand-by all the time).

```
Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. AMD A6-7310 APU, 12 GB DDR3. Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-72-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)
```

Comment: Any ideas? I still have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After installing Kernel 4.8 (hardware enablement stack), the issue disappeared.