# Google Chromium broken after installing nvidia drivers on ASUS ROG laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, asus, chromium

I've installed Xubuntu 16.10 with Nvidia binary drivers on ASUS ROG GL552VW and when I run chromium I got this look, it don't change when I enter different url in address bar.

[image]

When I opened the browser It opened last open tabs and when I switch I got the page but it don't change when I switch back to new tab (I have the same gray rectangles and the previous page)

[image]

Anybody had the same issue and resolve it?

The firefox is working and I have webGL working also (on default intel graphic card it was not working).

Comment: have you tried reinstalling chromium?

Comment: Which version of the nvidia drivers did you install? It's *possible* you are experiencing another manifestation of this bug: http://askubuntu.com/q/896221/518562

Comment: I've resolve the issue by removing config directory for chromium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by removing `~/.config/chromium` directory.