# Wake up from suspend increases CPU usage, unusable system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, cpu-load

Whenever I put my computer into suspend mode and then wake it up, I can see a great increase in CPU usage as well as a number of other glitches which make system unusable. The problem manifests itself both on AMD and Intel processors (checked with a friend's PC). I'm using NVIDIA for my graphic card with the latest 378.13 driver version, Ubuntu 16.10.

Here are the links to a couple of short videos that illustrate the problem:

1. [Unity](https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=Rnb4TV25W8U)
2. [i3 window manager, shows CPU usage](https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=Xaz-DbCsPRU)

I knew suspend was buggy, but interestingly it worked more or less ok on my previous PC (intel CPU + NVIDIA graphic). Not sure what exactly is at fault here, would appreciate any suggestions. Perhaps I should file a bug with either Nvidia or Ubuntu?

Comment: FYI, version 378.13 of the Nvidia driver [has a nasty bug.(https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode)