# Strange problems with graphics because of Window spreading?

Tags: graphics, windows

I have strange problem, when I wake laptop from sleeping. All Windows or messages have this strange pixels around them:

[image]

Sometimes it helps if I disable Windows spreading. Any idea?

Comment: Here's the information missing from your question: You have Nvidia graphics with a certain version of Nvidia drivers.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/901343/518562

Comment: Hey, I was guessing it was problem with nvidia drivers and I should write drivers version.  Thanks to Android Dev I found there was problem with known bug with drivers from nvidia. I updated nvidia drivers and problem is gone. Thanks for help!