# Nvidia driver causes reboot issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and have and Nvidia Geforce GTX960 in the laptop.  I was getting funny "white rectangles" surrounding the windows, so I figured it was just updating the graphics driver.  I dutifully looked up and installed the latest.

Except upon reboot, when it comes up and asks for my password, I get a never ending circle of events.  I type in the password, it thinks for a moment, accept my password, goes blank, and then comes back to ask again for my password.

No, the password is correct, because when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I can get right in, but still can't get in through the normal GUI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: And your issue about "white rectangles" is addressed here, make sure you have the very latest nvidia-381 driver from the graphics-drivers PPA: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode

Comment: So, 

I went to the suggested pages, and it was a bit of a help.  However, it took several more attempts and a LOT of reading in the nvidia archives to find the actual issues.  

So, when installing with the code from Nvidia "...run" the script first does a check to find linux-source code, which it subsequently uses to rebuild the driver on the spot.  However, reading their "how to" docs very thoroughly, i found that one has to revise the file /etc/x11/xorg.conf so that the "Device" section line identifying the driver says "nvidia" instead of "nouveau" (what mine said).

Comment: After changing that line, I called upon the 
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
then when I did the 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
after the install I was able to verify that I am now running nvidia and can now move on to working with Cuda.  :)

Comment: I'll work with the "white-ish rectangles" around the windows if they return (as that link mentioned that it came from certain nvidia driver versions.

Thanks again