# Can ubuntu 16.04, CUDA and nvidia-375 co-exist?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have two GTX 1080 installed with ubuntu 16.04. 
Everything works fine (Im using CUDA), until I restart the machine and it goes into a login loop. For some reason, I can't switch to tty mode from the login screen, so I have to boot the machine into recovery mode.

After I uninstall all the nvidia driver `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`, everything works again, I can login without problems.

So I reinstall the nvidia-375 again, the problem came back again.

I saw some posts saying that nvidia-36x works fine, but for CUDA 8.0, it needs nvidia-375.

I have disabled secure boot on the bios, Im not sure if it is because ubuntu not happy with unsigned kernel modules.

Anyone able to make them work together without the login loop?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, 375 has [a nasty bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/896221/518562).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, CUDA 8.0, with the Nvidia 375 driver without problems (well, other than the artifact problems).  I had originally installed CUDA when using the Nvidia 367 driver, which also worked without problems. The bug on the artifacts had a fix involved with killing compiz when awakening from sleep, which works for me.  However, I'm running in legacy mode, not UEFI.

Comment: Nvidia has released [an official fix for the artifacts bug.](https://askubuntu.com/a/901343/518562)