# Annoying hang at boot

Tags: nvidia, compiz, mate

#### Hello!

I have the following problem:
**Whenever I boot my system there is an annoying ~10 sec delay** when I log in and the desktop environment is loading. The screen just kind of freezes with half loaded window decorations (every window bar is gray). Every app I launch during this time freezes (for those 10 sec) and there are no desktop icons. There does not appear to be any significant CPU or HDD activity. After the delay, everything loads fine, icons on desktop appear.

The desktop environment I am using is Mate with Compiz compositor (switching to Marco does not fix this).

I have nVidia GTX750 Ti card running with proprietary 378.13 drivers that I installed from graphics-drivers PPA. To be able to boot, I am using `nomodeset` boot parameter.

The problem appears when using the proprietary driver - there is no delay with open source drivers.

#### What I have tried

I have run systemd-analyze and read jornalctl to find any source of delay, but to my untrained eye there is nothing. Just in case, here is the end of [journalctl (admin)](https://pastebin.com/1fgPp3v2).

#### What I would like to know

What could cause this delay?
Where can I look for problems/sources? Any service that I could blame?

Comment: FYI, the 378.13 Nvidia drivers have a known bug: https://askubuntu.com/q/896221/518562

Comment: Thanks a million!  
I already was put up with the fact that nVidia + Linux is a bumpy ride, but this appears to solve the problem. Will do some more tests soon (well.. reboots).