# Window Buttons and Shadows Broken After Resuming from Suspend

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, window

Whenever I suspend my laptop, than resume, Ubuntu gets broken graphics.
It looks like this:
[image: Image of Issue]
Fullscreen windows look fine, but all the non-fullscreen windows have broken shadows and navigation buttons.
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX960M (with 375.39 propiretary driver)

Comment: This is a [known bug in certain versions of the Nvidia driver.](https://askubuntu.com/a/901343/518562)