# Missing libcuda.so.1 file after upgrading to newest nvidia driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have upgraded to the latest (beta) Nvidia driver - `nvidia-381` due to an issue with the previous driver. I had a problem with window edges after waking from suspend - see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode/).

For this reason I upgraded to the newer driver, from `375.39` to `381.09`.

Since upgrading, I have had to reinstall Nvidia's [Cuda Toolkit 8.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) (and CUDNN v5.1), however there seems to be a driver file missing, which prevents me from installing both Tensorflow and the gputools package in R, which build upon the Cuda Toolkit, which in turn needs the missing libcuda.so.1 file.
Neither `Tensorflow` nor `gputools` are able to locate the file: `libcuda.so.1`. With the previous driver I was able to install the Cuda Toolkit without issues.

Here is a similar issue, but with older drivers involved: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4078

I have read that I could possibly create this file as it is a symlink, however I would prefer not to, as I do not know what other dependencies exist.
Example of possible workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890549/tensorflow-cannot-open-libcuda-so-1

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I have also posted this question on the [`Ubuntu launchpad`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1683512)

#### Questions:

1. Can somebody see why this file is missing or propose a stable solution?
2. If I am going to have to change my driver - which is the best way to downgrade and how to I decide which to downgrade to?

#### Extra info:

1. If I search for the missing file on my system, I find the following similar files, but not the one I need:

   ```
   user@user $ tree / -fiC | grep libcuda.so
       /usr/local/cuda-8.0/doc/man/man7/libcuda.so.7
       /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so
       /usr/share/man/man7/libcuda.so.7
   ```
2. If I look to see what the Nvidia driver would like to **uninstall**, should I use the given uninstallation script, then we see that it wasn't aware of the libcuda.so.1 file at installation, hence it isn't in this script:

   ```
   user@user $ /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin$ cat 

   .uninstall_manifest_do_not_delete.txt | grep libcuda.so
   file:/usr/share/man/man7/libcuda.so.7:5708adf9bb3c591eb4f1d0d50e78f3df
   file:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so:8347cb2f5500934b1942ba42f3979fac
   file:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/doc/man/man7/libcuda.so.7:5708adf9bb3c591eb4f1d0d50e78f3df
   ```
3. As there is the stub of the libcuda.so.1 file (seen in output above), I created the missing symlink to that file:

   ```
   user@user $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcuda.so.1
   ```

   This actually allowed the `gputools` package in R to be successfully installed, however the functions that call upon the GPU failed:

   ```
   R> gpuMatMult(matA, matB)
   Error in gpuMatMult(matA, matB) : device memory allocation failed Calls: gpuMatMult -> .Call
   ```
4. Using the `deviceQuery` utility that is bundled into the `samples` of the Cuda Toolkit (you have to first `sudo make` it), I see there is definitely something wrong, which Cuda notices itself:

   ```
   user@user $ /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery

       ./deviceQuery Starting...

       CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

       cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
       -> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
       Result = FAIL
   ```

### Current status:

I have downgraded to the previous driver I knew to work with the Cuda Toolkit 8.0, CUDNN 5.1 - `nvidia-378.13`. The tools that use Cuda and CUDNN are also now working fine as before, e.g. `tensorflow`, `gputools` (in R), etc.

Everything is working just as expected, including the bug showing pixelated window edges after waking from suspend.

Comment: For anybody who finds this, the open source `nvidia-381` driver doesn't include the `libcuda.so.1` file that is needed by both `tensorflow` and `theano`.  I spent hours trying to figure it out and `sudo apt install nvidia-378` along with a reboot got `libcuda.so.1` installed and still worked with my `1080 ti`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the problem, @Chris - you're solution (workaround) is just the same as mine though. There has not yet been a response on [Ubuntu Launchpad problem tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/theano/+bug/1683512).