# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop - Screen display errors / glich after suspend

Tags: 16.04, display, suspend, screen

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop. Every time i suspend the laptop and resume later i get many errors in the display like this

[image]

I get the same behaviour in Chrome, Terminal, every single application. i don't know that to do niether how to fix it.

Comment: Please check the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/901343/332744):
```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install nvidia-381
```

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same issue, then both of these threads popped up in search. :)