# Nvidia Graphics problem: strange artifacts even after install of v.381

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

Recently i have had the issue of strange artifacts after sleep mode. I ve updated my NVIDIA driver as stated in [Strange artifacts along window borders after waking computer from sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode/896544#896544) and all seem to work out.

I no longer have the issues around the windows but Viber seems to still be affected. The profile pictures and pics inside a chat are still acting weird!

Is there any more i can do or it's just the bug not fully fixed?

Answer (score -1):

Please restart compiz with:

```
compiz --replace
```

It worked for me. If it does not work, install the latest Nvidia driver "nvidia-381" which fixes the issue, you may not find it within standard repositories so please add it from a PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge nvidia*

sudo apt install nvidia-381
```

After this please reboot your computer and check if problem is gone.

I hope it helps.