# Weird graphics issues and random crashes in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 17.04

I have an acer predator laptop (G9-593-7757 15,6"/i7-7700/32 GB RAM/512 GB SSD/1 TB HDD/GTX1070 with ubuntu 17.04 and nvidia-375 graphics drivers.

Now for the last few days the computer has been misbehaving somewhat, it has been randomly crashing where the computer hangs for about a minute and then crashes me back to the login screen, certain programs continue to function where as others do not (mostly sound and graphics all crash). I also regularly get weird graphics effects as seen in this image (note that the background should be a bunch of formulas and text not whatever it is now) [image: picture of weird graphics artifacts]

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24468609/) is the xorg.log, it's too big for askubuntu.

I have noticed that these effects most often appear when low on battery (less then 20% left) but that might be a coincidence. Around the same time as this happened my system started booting really slowly (90 seconds or more), but that might not be related.

In case it matters here is the boot.log (given that booting is slow and it might be related).

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 480895/13000704 files, 27847421/52000000 blocks
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
         Activating swap /swapfile...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Swap.
         Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device /dev/disk/by-uuid/9CC9-E8AC.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/9CC9-E8AC...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sound Card.
         Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
         Activating swap /swapfile...
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/9CC9-E8AC.
         Mounting /boot/efi...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted /boot/efi.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up...
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting ebtables ruleset management...
         Starting Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
         Starting AppArmor initialization...
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console font and keymap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Starting Nameserver information manager...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Nameserver information manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ebtables ruleset management.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started AppArmor initialization.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Raise network interfaces.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Time Synchronized.


[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (30s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (31s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (32s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (32s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (32s / no limit)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (32s / no limit)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (33s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (34s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (35s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (35s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (35s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (35s / no limit)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (36s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (37s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (38s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (38s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (38s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (38s / no limit)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (39s / no limit)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (40s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (41s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (41s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (41s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (41s / no limit)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (42s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (43s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (44s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (44s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (44s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (44s / no limit)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (45s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (46s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (47s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (47s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (47s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (47s / no limit)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (48s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (49s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (50s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (50s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (50s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (50s / no limit)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (51s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (52s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (53s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (53s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (53s / no limit)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (53s / no limit)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (54s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (55s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (56s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (56s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (56s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (56s / no limit)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (57s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (58s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (59s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (59s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (59s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (59s / no limit)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min / no limit)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 1s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 2s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 2s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 2s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 2s / no limit)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 3s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 4s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 5s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 5s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 5s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 5s / no limit)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 6s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 7s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 8s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 8s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 8s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 8s / no limit)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 9s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 10s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 11s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 11s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 11s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 11s / no limit)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 12s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 13s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 14s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 14s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 14s / no limit)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 14s / no limit)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 15s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 16s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 17s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 17s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 17s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 17s / no limit)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 18s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 19s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 20s / 1min 30s)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 20s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 20s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 20s / no limit)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 21s / no limit)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 22s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 23s / 1min 30s)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 23s / 1min 30s)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 23s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 23s / no limit)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 24s / no limit)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 25s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 26s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 26s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 26s / no limit)
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 26s / no limit)
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] (1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device (1min 27s / no limit)
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 28s / 1min 30s)
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
[K[[0;1;31m TIME [0m] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66246dd6\x2d311e\x2d4948\x2d8fff\x2dd85a33f6f8c5.device.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Encrypted Volumes.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI Events Check.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Timer to automatically refresh installed snaps.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
         Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
         Starting LXD - unix socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Message of the Day.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on LXD - unix socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting LXD - container startup/shutdown...
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI event daemon.
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started FUSE filesystem for LXC.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
         Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Snappy daemon.
         Starting Auto import assertions from block devices...
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
         Starting Accounts Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting Bluetooth service...
         Starting LSB: Start the GNUstep distributed object mapper...
         Starting monitor and control system power state...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started CUPS Scheduler.
         Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started crash report submission daemon.
         Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Modem Manager...
         Starting Login Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Auto import assertions from block devices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Start the GNUstep distributed object mapper.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Bluetooth service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Login Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started monitor and control system power state.
         Starting Daemon for power management...
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting OpenVPN service...
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting Hostname Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
         Starting Authorization Manager...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Bluetooth.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started OpenVPN service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
         Starting Light Display Manager...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Authorization Manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Accounts Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Modem Manager.
```

I know this might be a bit wide so if I'm missing any important logs feel free to ask for it and thank you for your attention.

I just tried `compiz --replace` and that did not fix the errors (even temporally).

Comment: Occurs after sleep maybe? Then a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode

Comment: Can occur within minutes after boot, but it's worth noting that I have seen something about swap going wrong in the boot log.  compiz --replace did not resolve the issue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright my computer broke completely and has been returned to acer, turns out the motherboard and screen had to be replaced. That suggests this was an early warning of breaking hardware.