# Resolution Issue

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

So I recently install Linux Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my desktop and when I booted into the software I noticed I couldn't change the resolution it is currently stuck at 640x480 (4:3). I have looked up solutions and have tried but none have worked. I was wondering if any of you could help me with my issue. Hardware Specs are Nvidia GTX Geforce 1050Ti Graphics Card, AMD 6 Core Processor, ASRock Motherboard, and 8GB of DDR4 Ram. I would like to change the resolution to 1920x1080 60 thanks for helping

Regards, Haik

Comment: *I am assuming you don't need any hardware specs.* This is a quite ridiculous assumption. Please [edit] and post the hardware specs, namely graphics and proprietary drivers installed, if applicable.

Comment: Just added the hardware specs I wasn't able to be very specific because I have no idea how Linux worked and I wanted to try something new downloading it. I hope it helps you and thanks for taking your time!

Comment: Go to Settings > Software Properties > Additional drivers, select and apply the recommended drivers. Reboot.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That helped and now it is at the full resolution I desired! Thanks for taking your time and sorry for the inconvenience and the delay have a nice day!

Comment: @HaikIsikbay If you installed the 375 driver, then beware it has an ugly bug when waking from suspend: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/

Comment: @AndroidDev what do u mean by ugly bug?

Comment: @HaikIsikbay See the screenshots in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/

Comment: @AndroidDev Okay! Well I appreciate your support for warning me and informing me! Have a nice day!