# Window Scaling Problem

Tags: 16.04, unity, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have 2 monitors:
One has a resolution of 3840x2160, and the other one has 1280x1024.

Every time I move a window from one screen to the other the scaling of it gets messed up.

Lets say I lunched Google Chrome on my (main) 4K monitor and when I try to move it to the other screen everything in doesn't scale appropriately and stays the same size - thus it looks huge on the small monitor.

Is there any workaround for this?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA driver version 375.39 (proprietary, tested).

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

According to Android Dev's comment my NVIDIA driver version was bugged, so I updated to version 381.09. No difference with my problem though.

Comment: FYI, the 375.39 driver has bug when resuming from suspend; see this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode

Comment: @AndroidDev Thanks for letting me know! But that didn't solve my problem.