# Watching videos with NVIDIA drivers makes video lag

Tags: nvidia, video

Was trying to watch a video on my PC after I had just installed NVIDA drivers for my GTX 750ti but the video start to lag and get pixelated I switched back to the Nouveau display drivers and video stopped lagging. How can I fix this? I am running Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Which version of the Nvidia drivers did you install?

Comment: They were  375.39, but I got it fixed I just put the video output back to automatic.

Comment: FYI, 375.39 has a bug when resuming from suspend: https://askubuntu.com/q/896221/518562

Comment: I haven't had any issues so far but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: But I have been having another issue that I am hoping you could help me out with. I was trying to play Saints Row 3 and this message popped up I am to put it in an imgur link because It won't let me copy paste it into here. Here is the error message http://imgur.com/a/R550j