# Ubuntu will not boot normally

Tags: boot

I haven't used this computer in a few weeks and the only operating system on it is Ubuntu. When I went to boot it up, I got past the dell logo and then this message appears:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal

/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 453522/1559768 files, 111711786/62383360 blocks
```

Once the message appears the computer freezes. I hold the power button to restart the machine, and I enter the GRUB menu and can boot into recovery mode.

I am unable to normally boot Ubuntu and I've tried to search for a solution but was unsuccessful. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on Ubuntu boot up - "recovering journal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal)

Answer (score 1):

**fsck**

Let's manually check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p2`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**nomodeset**

Boot with video drivers disabled (temporary)...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
- find "quiet splash"
- change it to "quiet splash nomodeset"
- hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting
- if it fully boots, video resolution may be off (temporary)
- report back

**Nvidia**

It looks like an incorrect Nvidia server driver is installed.

Change to nividia-driver-440 or nouveau driver.

Report back.

**Update #1:**

`fsck` fixed the journal errors.

Booting with `nomodeset` allowed the computer to fully boot.

Switching to the nouveau video driver didn't help.

Purging Nvidia video drivers and installing Nvidia 450.66 did not fix the problem.

Going to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113208/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-will-not-boot-normally).