# Ubuntu 20.04 can't boot

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 is suddenly stuck at booting with following error. Beforehand, my laptop went to sleep and it froze so I hardly turned it off and that happened when I rebooted. It is a new installation. Please help.. Thanks! [image]

Comment: Do you have nvidia graphics card? Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276158/ubuntu-will-not-boot-normally

Comment: No, I'm using AMD