# Error on Ubuntu boot up with a new kernel - Stuck on recovering journal

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm trying to boot into Ubuntu and got this:
[image]

So I followed the instructions here:[Error on Ubuntu boot up - "recovering journal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal)

> To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...
> boot to the GRUB menu
> choose Advanced Options
> choose Recovery mode
> choose Root access
> at the # prompt, type sudo fsck -f /
> repeat the fsck command if there were errors
> type reboot

and stuck on here:
[image]

Again I used these instructions from [Error on Ubuntu boot up - "recovering journal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal)

> If for some reason you can't do the above...
> boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
> start gparted and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
> quit gparted
> open a terminal window
> type sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX # replacing X with the number you found earlier
> repeat the fsck command if there were errors
> type reboot

[image]
But nothing changed after that.
However, when I go to GRUB menu and change Ubuntu to an older kernel, it can boot up normally.
I want to figure out what's wrong with the kernel. Is this difficult?
Or should I change the default kernel version and stop update it? Will this have any adverse effects?

Comment: Can you include the versions of the kernel which do, and do not work for you?

Comment: @Charles Green The older one is Ubuntu, Linux 5.8.0-48-generic, the other one is Ubuntu, Linux 5.8.0-50-generic.

Comment: It's my understanding that the -50 kernel has a bug, and that it should be replaced soon.  The only advice I've seen on it suggested to use the -48 version until a -51 or later version becomes available.