# Running into Recovery journal error on booting Ubuntu all of a sudden

Tags: dual-boot

Before this question is closed for being a "Duplicate", please note that my issue isnt specifically about the `Recovery Journal` error, but an error which comes up trying to fix it through a possible solution

I currently have an Ubuntu Dual boot on Windows 11, which was working perfectly fine for the past few months, since I had installed it alongside my Windows Dell Laptop. Today, when I try booting into Ubuntu from the GRUB Loader, I get a

`dev/nvme0n1p7: clean m/n files, x/y blocks` message on a black screen. Along with something called "Recovery Journal"

After a quite a bit of research and googling I found out that this happened due to some corruption in my filesystem or partitions that I had made.

Some of the links mentioned to use the `sudo fsck -f /`  command under Ubuntu Recovery Mode, in the root access prompt

On doing this, I run into the following error message, which I haven't been able to resolve

`fsck.ext4: Unable 'UUID=some alphanumeric text'`

Can anyone help me in how I should go about resolving this? I have been stuck on this for quite a while and don't see any feasible solutions that work for my system :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if this isn't the correct sub-reddit to post this type of question in. Thanks in advance :')

Edit: Some solutions also mention using a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to get over this(This answer in specific: [Error on Ubuntu boot up - "recovering journal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal)).

However I don't think that's feasible for me as of now :(

0 Comments

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use a `USB-stick` you can use a `third party partitioning program` in `Windows` (1). Do NOT use `Windows DiskManager`, as this will screw up the `EXT4 partition` you need to repair even further. This is the easiest method of the three
(2) What you also can do is put an Ubuntu iso file in the root of your Windows-partition. Then you have to edit the grub.cfg in the EFI-partition to make it bootable. You need to add the following in that file.

```
menuentry "Xubuntu" {
insmod ext2
set isofile="/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,7)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject quiet splash toram
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

Replace `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso` with the name of your .iso
Replace `hd0,7` with the numbers of your disk. `0` is the first harddisk, `1` is the second etc. The number `7` is the `partitionnumber` your `Windows` is installed on. Usually you have the `EFI-partition` and then the `Windows-partition`. In that case it would be `2`. 
(3) This also works if you install `Grub2Win` in `Windows`. As the name implies it is `Grub` for `Windows`. Make the changes and save `Grub.cfg`. Then set `Grub2Win` as `default bootmanager`. 
When booting choose the `iso` as system you want to boot. Then you are in a `live Ubuntu`. You can then use `GParted` to repair your `EXT4-partition`.
Method 1 is the easiest, then 3 and then 2 (as you need to get access to the `EFI-partition` and how you do that in `Windows` I don't know (ask Dr. Google)).

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a detailed reply. I will try doing these steps and get back to you in case of any updates I might have