# So i am running ubuntu on a 2014 chromwbook wolf(with custom firmware) and it wont boot

Tags: boot-repair, chromebook

Sometimes, idk why, it boots to a screen that just says
dev/(idk what even) recovering journals
And it wont boot farther than that
Idk what to do, should i reinstall, or can i do something else
I got Mrchromebox haswell firmware

Comment: Welcome to AU. Unfortunately there’s nothing to go on here - please provide more information and someone will try to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on Ubuntu boot up - "recovering journal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the exact error message when it does not boot?