# When I close my laptop and then open it again (suspend/hibernate) I got strange images, why?

Tags: graphics

This is what I am getting when I close and open my laptop I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia driver 440

if you need more information let me know.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem in my Kubuntu installation. This happens on some laptops after suspending. I can't remind how I fixed it but I don't experience it anymore.

Comment: @adazem009, well remember pls, lol :D

Comment: I guess the way how to fix this is by reinstalling/updating your GPU drivers. Some of these issues also disappeared when I switched my GPU (I've got NVIDIA and Intel GPUs) using prime-select (see nvidia-prime package).

Comment: Hi again. After some experimenting with GPU drivers, I now have the same issue as you do. I'll try to fix it and then post an answer with the solution. But I think everything depends on the driver you use. I'm using NVIDIA 440 too right now, so that might be the cause. Try to switch the driver using the "Additional drivers" app.

Comment: @adazem009, yes I tried switching the driver, but I think it did not work :/

Comment: In the meantime I found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode/897641#897641

Comment: but nothing works from those posts, in order to fix it i have to do a full restart :/

Comment: Hmm... I really don't know how to fix that. I haven't experienced the same issue yet. I had those problems but they disappeared after some time.