# Artifacts on external display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display

I am facing an issue of artifacts on my secondary monitor, which happen *most*, but not all of the time. About 1/20 reboots, everything works as expected.

The problems are similar as the ones described here: [Strange artifacts along window borders after waking computer from sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode)

- I am on Ubuntu 23.04
- The system is a Lenovo IdeaPad C340-14
- I am using an NVIDIA GeForce MX230
- The secondary monitor is attached via HDMI and has a resolution of 1920x1080

Things I've already ruled out:

- It's not an issue with the screen itself, since works fine with a different PC
- It's also not an issue with the Laptop, since it works under Windows on the same machine

Things I've tried that don't seem to many any difference:

- Turning off the internal display
- Changing the drivers. All drivers available via the "Additional drivers" utility (proprietary and open source) are causing the same issue
- Doing a full re-install of Ubuntu
- Downgrading Ubuntu
- Forcing the system to use only the integrated graphics / dedicated GPU via the NVIDIA settings

Other things I've noticed:

- The issues do not appear when running am Ubuntu live USB
- About every 1 of 20 reboots, everything works perfectly fine
- I can reliably reproduce the artifacts by suspending and resuming from sleep
- Setting a lower resolution on the monitor makes the artifacts worse
- The issues do not appear on the login screen